# What is the maximum bandwidth (upload and download) and number of connections for an s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using s3 to feet multiple terabytes of data into a bioinformatics pipeline. I've got 20 nodes all in the same subnet copying a file from `s3://mybucket.com`, processing it, and uploading the results back to `s3://mybucket.com`. The copying speed to and from s3 is the bottleneck here.

If I have a single node copying a file, I get about 200Mib/s. but if I increase the number of nodes to say 200, they all slow down to very slow speeds between 5Mib/s and 15Mib/s and some don't copy at all.

My original thoughts were around the bandwidth of the subnet, but here's what [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/the-floodgates-are-open-increased-network-bandwidth-for-ec2-instances/) says about that:

> EC2 to S3 – Traffic to and from Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3) can
>   now take advantage of up to 25 Gbps of bandwidth.

What possible limits am I running into here and how can they be overcome?
Thanks!

Comment: What route are the packages taking? Are you using a NAT-gateway or IGW? Have you tested if a [VPC endpoint](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/) has an impact on the performance?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using an [S3 gateway endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html) inside your VPC. This also [reduces the S3 traffic cost to zero](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/pricing/), whereas via the internet is charged at standard internet rate.

If the tasks are parallel and the nodes don't communicate, you could try putting your instances into a few VPCs using a few gateway endpoints. This is just an idea, I haven't tried it. However, if they do communicate, this could significantly increase your bandwidth bill.

Comment: Are you sure that S3 VPC Endpoint is faster than a public one? Could be, I’m just thinking why it would be. Especially with S3 endpoints that are routed unlike endpoints for most other services that get an ENI inside the VPC.

Comment: My understanding is that the endpoint is basically a direct connection between the VPC and S3 across the AWS internal network. Standard access to S3 is via the internet, which seems like it should be slower. I can't find any performance test, just anecdotal comments. There is a tool to test the performance [here](https://github.com/jenshadlich/S3-Performance-Test), which someone could run if interested. S3 endpoints [don't charge for data](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/pricing/), whereas via the internet it does.